# How to replace 0 to null value in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, some of the cell in the dataframe have 0 , how to replace all the 0 with ' '  ?

```
final = final.replace(0, '')
```

This code not able run...Anyone can share me idea?

Comment: The code snippet you posted should've worked but it really depends on your actual data, please post raw data and code to reproduce your actual df

Comment: What is `final.dtypes`?

Comment: So maybe need `final = final.replace('0', '')`

Comment: dtype is object

Comment: So does jezrael's suggestion work?

Comment: **unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() > str()**

Comment: my 0 is a number

Comment: We really need a [MCVE] now.

Comment: the 0 replace from nan to 0 and used the 0 to do mathematical problem now need change back to nan...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
final = final.replace(0, np.nan)
              .style.apply(color, axis=None)
              .set_table_attributes('border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"')
              .set_precision(10)
              .render()
```

Comment: but my 0 is a number

Comment: it is in int type

Comment: All values are int? Or floats?

Comment: some are float some are integer

Comment: What return `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: is int , I try
` tableyy = final.style.apply(color, axis=None).set_table_attribute('border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table bordered"').set_precision(10).render()
  

    final = tableyy.replace(0, 'nan')`

but **Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly**

Comment: Is possible replace first?

Comment: impossible to replace first, but I try alternative way that is to set the color font to transparent so that 0 does not appear and it work